# Intercept all GCM push messages(for any app)

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am writing an app which would intercept/block any sort of push notification. The package name needs to be appended while setting permissions(from the GCM documentation). Refer to

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#manifest

Is it possible to intercept all GCM messages?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to intercept all GCM messages?

Fortunately, no, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

Comment: What about if we have information such as the package name and use the same credentials for both apps? I'm guessing bot apps would get unique reg ids.Am I right?

Comment: @Rohan: You cannot use the same credentials for both apps. The package name (application ID) is unique for the device. No two apps can be installed at the same time with the same package name.

Comment: How do  apps like these do it though? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.araneaapps.android.apps.notificationdisable

Comment: @Rohan: That app has nothing to do with GCM. That app manages `Notifications` (the icons in the status bar), presumably via an `AccessibilityService`.