# Receive WhatsApp messages to external app before the notification appears

Tags: android, push-notification, whatsapp

I want my app to receive WhatsApp messages, check the content (I'm planning to do some deep learning methods using the message content) and then push the notification and deside if to silence it or not.

Basically I'm building an application that silence non-urgent WhatsApp messages (using machine learning to deside whether it's urgent or not).

**How can I receive WhatsApp messages to my app and mute some of them?**

Comment: I don't understand... How would you get the message before Whatsapp sent it to you?

Comment: not before it gets to the phone. before it makes sound and notification

Comment: I would be interested in knowing if it's possible to silence your own push notifications. But as mentioned, it's not possible for other apps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37254064/intercept-all-gcm-push-messagesfor-any-app

Answer (score 0):

You can’t handle notifications of another application because their server sends a notification that only their application can handle.

This is how FCM works: [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/).

Comment: ok thanks, but can I mute whatsapp notifications? and how can I receive the message to my app?

Comment: You can’t do that because your application can only handle and manage your notifications.